# Spring and Postgres transaction Error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, postgresql-9.5

Currently, I am using Spring 4.0.6 with Postgresql 9.5. I am calling one `serviceClass1` to another `serviceClass2` and getting an exception for a transaction as following:

serviceClass1.class

```
`@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED,rollbackFor= { Throwable.class })
public Map<String, Object> storeUsersList(Map<String, Object> mapOfParams) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> returnMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
if (userListToStore != null && !userListToStore.isEmpty()) {                
integrationService.manangePassCodes(org,userListToStore.size());
                for (Users singleUser : userListToStore) {
                    try {
                        getEm().update(singleUser);`
```

serviceClass2.class

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly=false,propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED
     ,rollbackFor{Throwable.class})
public void manangePassCodes(Organizations org,int userToRegisterCount)throws Exception{
//some Logic
```

here I am getting Exception at this place - 
`getEm().update(singleUser);`

> Exception SQL state [25P02]; error code [0]; could not extract
>   ResultSet

I have just read about this error about Postgres transaction but not able to get what should I use for Hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the Speedy help and I have got my problem solved by inspecting more and reading about this error message above.I was calling many transactions from a single transaction and it means in my case that due to previous transaction error next is aborted because it had the write lock on the DB. and your current transaction will not be saved until you sort out previous one. **Previous Transaction which had silly mistake** `getEm().update(singleUser)`; **Current Transaction which has nothing wrong** `integrationService.manangePassCodes(org,userListToStore.size‌());`
 piece of code
Since both belong to different services but and I have annotated with
`@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false, rollbackFor = { Throwable.class })`
propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED means that it will Support a current transaction, create a new one if none exists.
So it gave me Error 25P02 - transaction aborted.

Reference Link 1 - [postgresql.org/message-id/25677724.post@talk.nabble.com](http://postgresql.org/message-id/25677724.post@talk.nabble.com)

Reference Link 2 - [postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/errcodes-appendix.htm](http://postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/errcodes-appendix.htm)

Reference Link 3 - https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/8829.1173816732%40sss.pgh.pa.us

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure if that is the case but in your `storeUsersList` method, you seem to be reusing already existing User collection which is stored in an instance variable `userListToStore`.

This collection of users is not initialized from inside of the transaction so the entities are most likely to be detached, as you are using container managed transactions.

In my opinion you should merge each of the entities before you perform the update, so that the persistence context is aware of them:

```
for (Users singleUser : userListToStore) {
      try {
        getEm().merge(singleUser);
        getEm().update(singleUser);
```

Comment: thanks but i have solved my problem by inspecting more and reading about this error message and I concluded that saving error is not at the `getEm().update(singleUser);`

Comment: sorry for existing comment.
thanks but I have solved my problem by inspecting more and reading about this error message above.
and it means that previous transaction is aborted next one can not proceed that saving error is not at the `getEm().update(singleUser);`
whereas it was at `integrationService.manangePassCodes(org,userListToStore.size());` piece of code
Reference Link 1 - https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/25677724.post@talk.nabble.com

Reference Link 2 - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/errcodes-appendix.html